# gcServer config not taking effect

Tags: asp.net, .net, web.config

I'm supporting a ASP.NET v2.0 app installed on a Windows 2003 SP3 Enterprise on a quad core 8G machine running on .NET 2.0 SP1.

1.before enabling the config, ran "tasklist /m mscorwks.dll"  
Image Name PID Modules
w3wp.exe 7888 mscorwks.dll

2.add under section in web.config

3.ran IISRESET, rebooted server too

4.ran "tasklist /m mscorsvr.dll" 
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

5.ran "tasklist /m mscorwks.dll" 
Image Name PID Modules 
w3wp.exe 6251 mscorwks.dll

It seems like gcServer is not taking effect. Are there any additional settings/ configurations necessary to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422533/gcserver-config-not-taking-effect

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.